# Zeeman eigenstates and QuTiP Bloch sphere

Tags: bloch-sphere, qutip

One Hamiltonian corresponding to a qubit is the Zeeman Hamiltonian:

$$
\hat{H}_\mathrm{Zeeman} = \frac{\hbar\omega_0}{2}\hat{\sigma_z}$$

The eigenstate corresponding to the eigenvaue $+\hbar\omega_0/2$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ (let us call it the **excited** state) while the eigenstate corresponding to the eigenvalue $-\hbar\omega_0/2$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ (let us call this the **ground** state).

In a qutip Bloch sphere, the exited state would be the one at the pole designated $\left|0\right\rangle$, while the ground state is at the $\left|1\right\rangle$ pole.

**But what if I want to put my ground state at the $\left|0\right\rangle$ pole? What would need to change if I do this?**

I know that this can easily be done if i just flip the sign of either $\omega_0$ or $\hat{\sigma_z}$, but is it possible to do this while keeping the Hamiltonian the same? Furthermore, is it possible for the dynamics to stay the same if this is done, i.e. an arbitrary state vector still precesses counterclockwise with respect to the positive $z$-axis?